# Punching: Make a fist and curl fingers correctly

Tags: technique, boxing, muay-thai, punching

I noticed that some people teach to make a fist like picture below, and clench fingers at the visible top part of hand (green line). However, doing this even after practicing flexibility, makes my hand stiff and unrelaxed.

So I curled fingers somewhat below green line now (say .5 to 1 centimeter below - slight adjustment).  Now my hand is Lot more relaxed, and punches are 25% Faster and powerful. Is there an issue with doing this? Does this cause hand injury? Punching the heavy bag (with and without glove), my hand feels there is no problem.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing incorrect about forming a fist as you describe in paragraph 2.

If I fold my fingers naturally, the tips of my fingers reach approximately 1 cm below the finger-palm line (the green line in your photo). I have never injured my fingers in over 2 decades of hitting heavy bags.

In fact, if your fingers naturally curl to this point, it will probably be impossible for you to curl your fingers correctly and keep them *above* the line.

When you form the proper fist, the tips of your fingers will likely be pressed into the middle of your palm.

The most important aspects of the fist are:

1. It is as compact (free from voids) as possible,
2. **The bones of the top of the fist are parallel with the bones of the forearm**, and
3. The thumb is curled around the middle phalanxes of your first two fingers (The thumb will likely reach only to the centre of the second finger, closer to the second knuckle).

As you probably know very well - and as most coaches point out during a student's first lesson - the thumb should never be kept *inside* the fingers.

The fact you experience no discomfort when punching using a fist as you describe is a good indication that your fist is adequate. It is very difficult to execute a powerful strike using a poor fist without experiencing discomfort/pain/injury.

Comment: another question here, https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/13332/punching-with-knuckles-correctly thanks